# selenium-webdriver: How to use for loop to find_elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get all the links and start_time and end_time one a page and then send to function(parse_detail) to scrap another information 
But I don't know how to use selenium to for loop

Here is my code
AND there is error:

```
for site in sites:
exceptions.TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Please teach me how to use for loop like scrapy in selenium. Thank you!

```
class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "city20140808"
    start_urls = ['http://wwwtt.tw/11']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        item  = CitytalkItem()
        sites = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.body ")
        for site in sites:
            linkiwant = site.find_element_by_css_selector(".heading a")
            start = site.find_element_by_css_selector("div.content p.m span.date")
            end = site.find_element_by_css_selector("div.content p.m span.date")

            item['link'] = linkiwant.get_attribute("href") 
            item['start_date']  = start.text
            item['end_date']  = end.text
            yield Request(url=item['link'], meta={'items':items}, callback=self.parse_detail)  
     def parse_detail(self,response):
        item = response.meta['items']
        ........
        yield item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `find_element_by_css_selector()`, which returns a single element, you need to use [`find_elements_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector), which returns a list of elements.